# Number of rows of query - Yii

Tags: sql, yii

i want to get the number of rows returned by a query in Yii. This is my query :

```
        $programsAlreadyExist = $connection->createCommand('
                SELECT *
                FROM `cat_programme` 
                WHERE `programme_code` = 513')
                ->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "COUNT" keyword should return a row containing the requested number. :-)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cat_programme WHERE programme_code = 513
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the SELECT to:

```
SELECT count (*) FROM cat_programme WHERE programme_code = '513'
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You could also do if via the `count()` method

For ecample

```
$programsAlreadyExist = MyModel::find()
    ->where(['programme_code' => '513'])
    ->count();
```